# Copying Bytes to Bytes Array?

Tags: c++

I am learning and I'd like to know the best way how to do the following array copy, Consider this code:

```
void Cast1LineSpell(UINT Serial, char *chant)
{
    byte packet[] = { 0x0F, 0x03, 
        (Serial >> 24) & 0xFF, (Serial >> 16) & 0xFF,(Serial >> 8) & 0xFF, Serial & 0xFF, 
        0x9A, 0x92, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1A };

    byte prepareSpell[2] = { 0x4D, 0x01 };

    byte chant_length = sizeof(chant) / sizeof(chant[0]);
    byte chant_name[] = { 0x4E, chant_length, }; // <= how can i put the bytes in chant* into the rest of this array, and then append bytes 0x00 and 0x4E on to the end of it?
}
```

how can i put the bytes that are inside of `*chant`, and then put them into the end of `chant[]` and then append bytes `0x00` and `0x4E` on to the end of it?

Can anybody provide a solution?
Much Appreciated.

Comment: How should that work? What output do you expect?

Comment: I'd like chant[]  to have the output of 0x4D, 0x01, chant_length, whatever is in *chant, 0x00, 0x4E

Comment: You'd be better off using a container like `std::vector<char>` since this is tagged **C++**..

Comment: If I use a container, how can I convert it into bytes?

Comment: If you use a `std::vector<char>` then you can convert it to `char*` using `v.data()` or `&v[0]` _(assuming its not empty)_.

Comment: what is `byte` - this isn't a C++ type.

Answer (score 0):

You are using *dynamic arrays* so the `sizeof(chant)` will always be the size of a pointer, and `sizeof(chant) / sizeof(chant[0])` won't be the number of elements in the array. That only works for *static arrays*.

Also, you are redeclaring `chant` which is simply an error.

In conclusion, since you do not know the number of elements in `chant`, there is no way to do what you want to do.

Comment: I don't know what you mean I thought sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) gives me the number of elemenths?

Comment: @Dean: It does when applied to a _static array_, not when you apply it to a pointer. The size of a pointer is not the same as the size of an array...

Comment: @Dean (And by "static array" we mean "array".)

Comment: The object has to be an array *type* for `sizeof` to return the size of the array. It doesn't matter whether it is statically allocated or dynamically allocated or variable length array, it just has to be an *array type*, and `char *` is not an array type, it is a pointer type.

Comment: @dreamlax: That's a nice way to put it!

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, in C++, all arrays passed into a function are treated as pointers no matter they are statically allocated or dynamically allocated or even you write the argument as `char chant[]`, (i.e., only the address of the first element is passed in).

Example:

```
void f(int value[]){
    cout<<"size in f: "<<sizeof(value)/sizeof(int)<<endl;
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    cout<<"size in main: "<<sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)<<endl;

    f(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

the result is:

```
size in main: 8
size in f: 1
```

So as you can see, in `f()`, `value[]` is the same as `value *`, and `sizeof(value)` is the size of the pointer.

You should (always) also pass in the length when you pass an array into a function.

```
void f(int value[], size_t size){
    cout<<"size in f: "<<size<<endl;
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

    cout<<"size in main: "<<size<<endl;

    f(arr, size);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
size in main: 8
size in f: 8
```